# Get a file name from a path

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the simplest way to get the file name that from a path?

```
string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat"
```

In this example, I should get "MyFile". without extension.

Comment: Search from the back until you hit a backspace?

Comment: @KerrekSB, you mean *backslash* ;)

Comment: i have an std::string that contains a path of a file "c:\\MyDirectory\\Myfile.pdf" i need to rename this file to myfile_md.pdf so i need to get the file name from the path.

Comment: If you need to do a lot of work with file paths consider using Boost FileSystem http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm

Comment: @Nim: Yes! I must have been spacing out...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[_splitpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath) should do what you need. You could of course do it manually but `_splitpath` handles all special cases as well.

EDIT:

As BillHoag mentioned it is recommended to use the more safe version of `_splitpath` called [_splitpath_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-s-wsplitpath-s) when available.

Or if you want something portable you could just do something like this

```
std::vector<std::string> splitpath(
  const std::string& str
  , const std::set<char> delimiters)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;

  char const* pch = str.c_str();
  char const* start = pch;
  for(; *pch; ++pch)
  {
    if (delimiters.find(*pch) != delimiters.end())
    {
      if (start != pch)
      {
        std::string str(start, pch);
        result.push_back(str);
      }
      else
      {
        result.push_back("");
      }
      start = pch + 1;
    }
  }
  result.push_back(start);

  return result;
}

...
std::set<char> delims{'\\'};

std::vector<std::string> path = splitpath("C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat", delims);
cout << path.back() << endl;
```

Comment: There's no `_splitpath` in any of the includes on my machine.

Comment: @JamesKanze maybe you dont have Visual Studio as the OP?

Comment: I have Visual Studio, **and** g++, and Sun CC.  Why should I use something non-standard when there are perfectly good portable solutions.

Comment: I guess it depends on the requirements.

Comment: @James, the page linked to says it is in `<stdlib.h>`. As for portability, perhaps you can list some examples of “perfectly good portable solutions”?

Comment: @Anders, what do you mean by “special cases”? The page doesn’t mention UNC paths which I suppose is one sort of special case.

Comment: @Synetech The page linked to describes a Microsoft extension, not `<stdlib.h>`.  And the mot obvious portable solution is `boost::filesystem`.

Comment: @James, you don’t have `_splitpath` in the `stdlib.h` of your copy of VS? Then you may want to do a repair install of VS.

Comment: Boost would be the way to go. If your code base is already using Windows APIs and you want to be consistent, use the more secure `_splitpath_s` rather than  '_splitpath'.

Comment: @BillHoag good point, will add that. As to boost, well sometimes boost is not available e.g. where I work boost is not allowed (yeah I know).

Answer (score 99):

The task is fairly simple as the base filename is just the part of the string starting at the last delimeter for folders:

```
std::string base_filename = path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1)
```

If the extension is to be removed as well the only thing to do is find the last `.` and take a `substr` to this point

```
std::string::size_type const p(base_filename.find_last_of('.'));
std::string file_without_extension = base_filename.substr(0, p);
```

Perhaps there should be a check to cope with files solely consisting of extensions (ie `.bashrc`...)

If you split this up into seperate functions you're flexible to reuse the single tasks:

```
template<class T>
T base_name(T const & path, T const & delims = "/\\")
{
  return path.substr(path.find_last_of(delims) + 1);
}
template<class T>
T remove_extension(T const & filename)
{
  typename T::size_type const p(filename.find_last_of('.'));
  return p > 0 && p != T::npos ? filename.substr(0, p) : filename;
}
```

The code is templated to be able to use it with different `std::basic_string` instances (i.e. `std::string` & `std::wstring`...)

The downside of the templation is the requirement to specify the template parameter if a `const char *` is passed to the functions.

So you could either:

#### A) Use only `std::string` instead of templating the code

```
std::string base_name(std::string const & path)
{
  return path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
}
```

#### B)  Provide wrapping function using `std::string` (as intermediates which will likely be inlined / optimized away)

```
inline std::string string_base_name(std::string const & path)
{
  return base_name(path);
}
```

#### C) Specify the template parameter when calling with `const char *`.

```
std::string base = base_name<std::string>("some/path/file.ext");
```

### Result

```
std::string filepath = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";
std::cout << remove_extension(base_name(filepath)) << std::endl;
```

Prints

```
MyFile
```

Comment: In this use case everything is OK (and original question is answered), but your extension remover is not perfect - it will fail if we pass there something like "/home/user/my.dir/myfile"

Comment: @avtomaton The extension removing function should be used on a file name not a path. (Just apply `base_name` first.)

Comment: I understand it (that's why I wrote that original question is answered and in this use-case everything is OK). Just wanted to point out to this issue for somebody who will try to use these snippets.

Comment: Very nice explanation. It enhances the structural understanding of the problem. Thanks

Comment: The backslash is actually a valid filename character on Unix. Your solution gives the wrong result for the Unix path `/home/user/my\file.txt`.

Answer (score 71):

A possible solution:

```
string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";

// Remove directory if present.
// Do this before extension removal incase directory has a period character.
const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.find_last_of("\\/");
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
{
    filename.erase(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
}

// Remove extension if present.
const size_t period_idx = filename.rfind('.');
if (std::string::npos != period_idx)
{
    filename.erase(period_idx);
}
```

Answer (score 70):

The Simplest way in C++17 is:

use the `#include <filesystem>` and `filename()` for filename with extension and `stem()` without extension.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
  std::string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";

  std::cout << fs::path(filename).filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path(filename).stem() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/bar.txt").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/bar.txt").stem() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/.bar").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/bar/").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/.").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/foo/..").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path(".").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("..").filename() << '\n'
    << fs::path("/").filename() << '\n';
}
```

Which can be compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -lstdc++fs`, and outputs:

```
"MyFile.bat"
"MyFile"
"bar.txt"
"bar"
".bar"
""
"."
".."
"."
".."
"/"
```

Reference: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename)

Comment: it is not in "experimental" anymore

Comment: Naming: do you know why `stem` over `basename`?

Answer (score 40):

The simplest solution is to use something like `boost::filesystem`.  If
for some reason this isn't an option...

Doing this correctly will require some system dependent code: under
Windows, either `'\\'` or `'/'` can be a path separator; under Unix,
only `'/'` works, and under other systems, who knows.  The obvious
solution would be something like:

```
std::string
basename( std::string const& pathname )
{
    return std::string( 
        std::find_if( pathname.rbegin(), pathname.rend(),
                      MatchPathSeparator() ).base(),
        pathname.end() );
}
```

, with `MatchPathSeparator` being defined in a system dependent header 
as either:

```
struct MatchPathSeparator
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ch == '/';
    }
};
```

for Unix, or:

```
struct MatchPathSeparator
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ch == '\\' || ch == '/';
    }
};
```

for Windows (or something still different for some other unknown
system).

EDIT:  I missed the fact that he also wanted to suppress the extention.
For that, more of the same:

```
std::string
removeExtension( std::string const& filename )
{
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator
                        pivot
            = std::find( filename.rbegin(), filename.rend(), '.' );
    return pivot == filename.rend()
        ? filename
        : std::string( filename.begin(), pivot.base() - 1 );
}
```

The code is a little bit more complex, because in this case, the base of
the reverse iterator is on the wrong side of where we want to cut.
(Remember that the base of a reverse iterator is one behind the
character the iterator points to.)  And even this is a little dubious: I
don't like the fact that it can return an empty string, for example.
(If the only `'.'` is the first character of the filename, I'd argue
that you should return the full filename.  This would require a little
bit of extra code to catch the special case.)
    }

Comment: How about using `string::find_last_of` instead of manipulating reverse iterators?

Comment: @LucTouraille Why learn two ways of doing things when one will do?  You'd need the reverse iterators for any container except `string`, so you have to learn them anyway.  And having learned them, there's no reason to bother learning all of the bloated interface to `std::string`.

Comment: Note: The [<filesystem>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx) header ships with Visual Studio 2015 and above, so you don't have to add a dependency on boost to use it.

Answer (score 17):

If you can use boost,

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
boost::filesystem::path p("C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat");
string basename = p.filename().string();
//or 
//string basename = boost::filesystem::path("C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat").filename().string();
```

This is all.

I recommend you to use boost library. Boost gives you a lot of conveniences when you work with C++. It supports almost all platforms.
If you use Ubuntu, you can install boost library by only one line `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` (ref. [How to install Boost on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu))

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the shell Path APIs PathFindFileName, PathRemoveExtension.  Probably worse than _splitpath for this particular problem, but those APIs are very useful for all kinds of path parsing  jobs and they take UNC paths, forward slashes and other weird stuff into account.

```
wstring filename = L"C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";
wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileName(filename.c_str());
PathRemoveExtension(filepart);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589(v=vs.85).aspx

The drawback is that you have to link to shlwapi.lib, but I'm not really sure why that's a drawback.

Comment: My preferred solution for getting a filename from a path.

Answer (score 14):

**Function:**

```
#include <string>

std::string
basename(const std::string &filename)
{
    if (filename.empty()) {
        return {};
    }

    auto len = filename.length();
    auto index = filename.find_last_of("/\\");

    if (index == std::string::npos) {
        return filename;
    }

    if (index + 1 >= len) {

        len--;
        index = filename.substr(0, len).find_last_of("/\\");

        if (len == 0) {
            return filename;
        }

        if (index == 0) {
            return filename.substr(1, len - 1);
        }

        if (index == std::string::npos) {
            return filename.substr(0, len);
        }

        return filename.substr(index + 1, len - index - 1);
    }

    return filename.substr(index + 1, len - index);
}
```

**Tests:**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include <catch/catch.hpp>

TEST_CASE("basename")
{
    CHECK(basename("") == "");
    CHECK(basename("no_path") == "no_path");
    CHECK(basename("with.ext") == "with.ext");
    CHECK(basename("/no_filename/") == "no_filename");
    CHECK(basename("no_filename/") == "no_filename");
    CHECK(basename("/no/filename/") == "filename");
    CHECK(basename("/absolute/file.ext") == "file.ext");
    CHECK(basename("../relative/file.ext") == "file.ext");
    CHECK(basename("/") == "/");
    CHECK(basename("c:\\windows\\path.ext") == "path.ext");
    CHECK(basename("c:\\windows\\no_filename\\") == "no_filename");
}
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

From C++ Docs - **[string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)**

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string

void SplitFilename (const std::string& str) {
  std::cout << "Splitting: " << str << '\n';
  unsigned found = str.find_last_of("/\\");
  std::cout << " path: " << str.substr(0,found) << '\n';
  std::cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << '\n';
}

int main () {
  std::string str1 ("/usr/bin/man");
  std::string str2 ("c:\\windows\\winhelp.exe");

  SplitFilename (str1);
  SplitFilename (str2);

  return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Splitting: /usr/bin/man
 path: /usr/bin
 file: man
Splitting: c:\windows\winhelp.exe
 path: c:\windows
 file: winhelp.exe
```

Comment: Don't forget (and to handle) that `find_last_of` returns `string::npos` if nothing was found.

Comment: @congusbongus True, but there is no sense of splitting the file path when it is just a file name (without path) :)

Comment: @jave.web It does make sense and MUST handle returns 'string::npos'. Implementing a function for this should be able to handle different inputs including "just filename". Otherwise, it will be useless if its buggy in actual implementation.

Comment: @winux This considers already **valid** *PATHS*... If you don't trust the input, you should, of course, validate the path first.

Comment: @winux **Anyway** the check for `string::npos` does not need to be done because of the way how this and `string::substr` are implemented. a) `string::npos`  is passed as "length" => `substr` has documented behaviour of reading all until end. b) `substr` is given "`string::npos + 1`" and no length: `string::npos` is documented to have a value of `-1`, so that evaluates to `0` => start of the string and lengths' default value for `substr` is the `npos` => works on "just filename" too
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Answer (score 7):

C++11 variant (inspired by James Kanze's version) with uniform initialization and anonymous inline lambda.

```
std::string basename(const std::string& pathname)
{
    return {std::find_if(pathname.rbegin(), pathname.rend(),
                         [](char c) { return c == '/'; }).base(),
            pathname.end()};
}
```

It does not remove the file extension though.

Comment: Short and sweet, although it only works with non-Windows paths.

Comment: you can always change lambda return to `return c == '/' || c == '\\';` to make it works on windows

Comment: To handle paths such as "", "///", and "dir1/dir2/", add the following code 
before the return statement above (cf. POSIX basename()):

   `if (pathname.size() == 0)
        return ".";
    auto iter = pathname.rbegin();
    auto rend = pathname.rend();
    while (iter != rend && *iter == '/')                   
        ++iter;
    if (iter == rend) /* pathname has only path separators */
        return "/";
    pathname = std::string(pathname.begin(), iter.base());`

Answer (score 6):

The `boost` `filesystem` library is also available as the `experimental/filesystem` library and was merged into ISO C++ for C++17. You can use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main () {
    std::cout << fs::path("/foo/bar.txt").filename() << '\n'
}
```

Output:

```
"bar.txt"
```

It also works for `std::string` objects.

Answer (score 4):

this is the only thing that actually finally worked for me:

```
#include "Shlwapi.h"

CString some_string = "c:\\path\\hello.txt";
LPCSTR file_path = some_string.GetString();
LPCSTR filepart_c = PathFindFileName(file_path);
LPSTR filepart = LPSTR(filepart_c);
PathRemoveExtension(filepart);
```

pretty much what Skrymsli suggested but doesn't work with wchar_t*, 
VS Enterprise 2015

_splitpath worked as well, but I don't like having to guess at how many char[?] characters I'm going to need; some people probably need this control, i guess.

```
CString c_model_name = "c:\\path\\hello.txt";
char drive[200];
char dir[200];
char name[200];
char ext[200];
_splitpath(c_model_name, drive, dir, name, ext);
```

I don't believe any includes were needed for _splitpath. No external libraries (like boost) were needed for either of these solutions.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string getfilename(std::string path)
{
    path = path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
    size_t dot_i = path.find_last_of('.');
    return path.substr(0, dot_i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it by...

Search backwards from the end of the string until you find the first backslash/forward slash.

Then search backwards again from the end of the string until you find the first dot (.)

You then have the start and end of the file name.

Simples...

Comment: Which doesn't work for any system I know.  (The one system which accepts `'\\'` as a path separator **also** uses `'/'`, so you need to match either.)  And I'm not sure what you'd be looking forward for.

Comment: Okay so modify it to match either, no biggy. And looking forward for the first dot (.)

Comment: You still have to find the last dot, not the first.  (Reverse iterators are your friend!)

Comment: Ah yes, good point. So for a file.ext.ext then you would want to extract file.ext wouldn't you. :)

Comment: Presumably.  That's the usual convention, in any case: `my.source.cpp` gets compiled to `my.source.obj`, for example (with the extension `.cpp` replaced with `.obj`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the std::filesystem to do it quite nicely:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

fs::path myFilePath("C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat");
fs::path filename = myFilePath.stem();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m_szFilePath.MakeLower();
CFileFind finder;
DWORD buffSize = MAX_PATH;
char longPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD result = GetLongPathName(m_szFilePath, longPath, MAX_PATH );

if( result == 0)
{
    m_bExists = FALSE;
    return;
}
m_szFilePath = CString(longPath);
m_szFilePath.Replace("/","\\");
m_szFilePath.Trim();
//check if it does not ends in \ => remove it
int length = m_szFilePath.GetLength();
if( length > 0 && m_szFilePath[length - 1] == '\\' )
{
    m_szFilePath.Truncate( length - 1 );
}
BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(this->m_szFilePath);
if(bWorking){
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
    finder.GetCreationTime(this->m_CreationTime);
    m_szFilePath = finder.GetFilePath();
    m_szFileName = finder.GetFileName();

    this->m_szFileExtension = this->GetExtension( m_szFileName );

    m_szFileTitle = finder.GetFileTitle();
    m_szFileURL = finder.GetFileURL();
    finder.GetLastAccessTime(this->m_LastAccesTime);
    finder.GetLastWriteTime(this->m_LastWriteTime);
    m_ulFileSize = static_cast<unsigned long>(finder.GetLength());
    m_szRootDirectory = finder.GetRoot();
    m_bIsArchive = finder.IsArchived();
    m_bIsCompressed = finder.IsCompressed();
    m_bIsDirectory = finder.IsDirectory();
    m_bIsHidden = finder.IsHidden();
    m_bIsNormal = finder.IsNormal();
    m_bIsReadOnly = finder.IsReadOnly();
    m_bIsSystem = finder.IsSystem();
    m_bIsTemporary = finder.IsTemporary();
    m_bExists = TRUE;
    finder.Close();
}else{
    m_bExists = FALSE;
}
```

The variable m_szFileName contains the fileName.

Comment: wow - that's a lot of code for "get file name" from path... :)

Comment: @Nim My impression as well.  In my own code, I use a one-liner: `boost::filesystem::path( path ).filename()`.

Comment: I have a CFileInfo class that has that code. I just dumped the code here because it is tested and I did not want to risk anything... You could just use about 5 lines of code from this example.

Answer (score 2):

This should work too :

```
// strPath = "C:\\Dir\\File.bat" for example
std::string getFileName(const std::string& strPath)
{
    size_t iLastSeparator = 0;
    return strPath.substr((iLastSeparator = strPath.find_last_of("\\")) != std::string::npos ? iLastSeparator + 1 : 0, strPath.size() - strPath.find_last_of("."));
}
```

If you can use it, Qt provide QString (with split, trim etc), QFile, QPath, QFileInfo etc to manipulate files, filenames and directories. And of course it's also cross plaftorm.

Comment: For the sake of the future readers of your code, please use temporary variables with meaningful names instead of stuffing everything into a single line of code (and while you're at it, please encapsulate all this into a function `getFilename` or something like that).

Comment: edited. But the point was to make it short, as several working answers already have been given.

Comment: I think it is WRONG.
Should not you replace the last part:
"strPath.size() - strPath.find_last_of(".")"
by
"strPath.find_last_of(".") - iLastSeparator"

Comment: @taktak004 you are right, it should be

 `    return strPath.substr(
     (iLastSeparator = strPath.find_last_of("/")) != std::string::npos ? iLastSeparator + 1 : 0,
     strPath.find_last_of(".") - iLastSeparator
 );`

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `_splitpath()` and `_wsplitpath()`. They are not safe, and they are obsolete!

Instead, use their safe versions, namely [`_splitpath_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [`_wsplitpath_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A really simple and short function that returns the filename+path that I made which uses no dependencies:

```
const char* GetFileNameFromPath(const char* _buffer)
{
    char c;
    int  i;
    for (i = 0; ;++i) {
        c = *((char*)_buffer+i);
        if (c == '\\' || c == '/')
            return GetFileNameFromPath((char*)_buffer + i + 1);
        if (c == '\0')
            return _buffer;
    }
    return "";
}
```

To only get the filename *without the extension* you could change `c == '\0'` to `c == '.'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string filepath = "directory/file-name.txt";
    
  std::string filename = filepath.substr(filepath.find_last_of("/")+1, filepath.find_last_of(".") - filepath.find_last_of("/") - 1);
  
  std::cout << filename << std::endl;
}
```

Returns:

```bash
file-name
```

Answer (score 0):

For long time I was looking for a function able to properly decompose file path. For me this code is working perfectly for both Linux and Windows.

```
void decomposePath(const char *filePath, char *fileDir, char *fileName, char *fileExt)
{
    #if defined _WIN32
        const char *lastSeparator = strrchr(filePath, '\\');
    #else
        const char *lastSeparator = strrchr(filePath, '/');
    #endif

    const char *lastDot = strrchr(filePath, '.');
    const char *endOfPath = filePath + strlen(filePath);
    const char *startOfName = lastSeparator ? lastSeparator + 1 : filePath;
    const char *startOfExt = lastDot > startOfName ? lastDot : endOfPath;

    if(fileDir)
        _snprintf(fileDir, MAX_PATH, "%.*s", startOfName - filePath, filePath);

    if(fileName)
        _snprintf(fileName, MAX_PATH, "%.*s", startOfExt - startOfName, startOfName);

    if(fileExt)
        _snprintf(fileExt, MAX_PATH, "%s", startOfExt);
}
```

Example results are:

```
[]
  fileDir:  ''
  fileName: ''
  fileExt:  ''

[.htaccess]
  fileDir:  ''
  fileName: '.htaccess'
  fileExt:  ''

[a.exe]
  fileDir:  ''
  fileName: 'a'
  fileExt:  '.exe'

[a\b.c]
  fileDir:  'a\'
  fileName: 'b'
  fileExt:  '.c'

[git-archive]
  fileDir:  ''
  fileName: 'git-archive'
  fileExt:  ''

[git-archive.exe]
  fileDir:  ''
  fileName: 'git-archive'
  fileExt:  '.exe'

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\.htaccess]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\'
  fileName: '.htaccess'
  fileExt:  ''

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\a.exe]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\'
  fileName: 'a'
  fileExt:  '.exe'

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-archive.exe]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\'
  fileName: 'git-archive'
  fileExt:  '.exe'

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git.core\git-archive.exe]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git.core\'
  fileName: 'git-archive'
  fileExt:  '.exe'

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-archiveexe]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\'
  fileName: 'git-archiveexe'
  fileExt:  ''

[D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git.core\git-archiveexe]
  fileDir:  'D:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git.core\'
  fileName: 'git-archiveexe'
  fileExt:  ''
```

I hope this helps you also :)

Answer (score 0):

`shlwapi.lib/dll` uses the `HKCU` registry hive internally.

It's best not to link to `shlwapi.lib` if you're creating a library or the product does not have a UI.  If you're writing a lib then your code can be used in any project including those that don't have UIs.

If you're writing code that runs when a user is not logged in (e.g. service [or other] set to start at boot or startup) then there's no `HKCU`.  Lastly, shlwapi are settlement functions; and as a result high on the list to deprecate in later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A slow but straight forward regex solution:

```
    std::string file = std::regex_replace(path, std::regex("(.*\\/)|(\\..*)"), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a function that might meet your needs.
It is based on string_view's **constexpr** function ***find_last_of*** (since c++17) which can be calculated at **compile time**

```cpp
constexpr const char* base_filename(const char* p) {
    const size_t i = std::string_view(p).find_last_of('/');
    return std::string_view::npos == i ? p : p + i + 1 ;
}

//in the file you used this function
base_filename(__FILE__);
```