# Find only file name from full path of the file in vc++

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++

Suppose there is a CString variable which store the full path of the file.Now I hava to find only file name from if.How to do it in vc++.

```
CString FileName = "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\FolderName\abc.dll";
```

Now I want only **abc.dll**.

Comment: you must escape your backslashes

Comment: I recommend the function decomposePath described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520560/get-a-file-name-from-a-path/42424844#42424844).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Same as already stated above, but as u are using MFC framework, this would be the way to do it. Though this does not check files existence.

```
CString path= "c:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\FolderName\\abc.dll";
CString fileName= path.Mid(path.ReverseFind('\\')+1);
```

Comment: BTW CString is not just for MFC - see <atlstr.h>. More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`PathFindFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Remember that you have to escape the `\` character in your path string!

Comment: @Mark, Why to convert? If it is char* - ANSI build, pass char* !

Answer (score 7):

```
std::string str = "c:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\FolderName\\abc.dll";
std::string res = str.substr( str.find_last_of("\\") + 1 );
```

Will get you "abs.dll".

Comment: Why use std::string when you have CString which has the required functions

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Boost::FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for filename manipulation as it understands what the parts of a name would be. The function you want here would be filename()

If you are just getting the filename you can do this using CString functions. First find the ast backslash using ReverseFind and then Right to get the string wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The code below demonstrate extracting a file name from a full path

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string get_file_name_from_full_path(const std::string& file_path)
{
    std::string file_name;

    std::string::const_reverse_iterator it = std::find(file_path.rbegin(), file_path.rend(), '\\');
    if (it != file_path.rend())
    {
        file_name.assign(file_path.rbegin(), it);
        std::reverse(file_name.begin(), file_name.end());
        return file_name;
    }
    else
        return file_name;
}

int main()
{
    std::string file_path = "c:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\FolderName\\abc.dll";
    std::cout << get_file_name_from_full_path(file_path) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```