# Multiple file selection from dialog box

Tags: mfc

I want to launch a dialog box in MFC, select multiple files and show this file to the user and later copy this file to another location.

I have written this code to try and achieve this:

```
CFileDialog fOpenDlg(TRUE,"", " ", OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, 
"Capture file (*.cap)|*.cap|", this);

fOpenDlg.m_pOFN->lpstrTitle="Import file";

fOpenDlg.m_pOFN->lpstrInitialDir="Desktop";

if(fOpenDlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
{
    POSITION pos=fOpenDlg.GetStartPosition();
    while(pos)
    {
        CString PathName=fOpenDlg.GetNextPathName(pos);
        CString strFileName=fOpenDlg.GetFilename();
        AfxMessageBox(strFileName);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I select single file it gives file name but when I select multiple files it does not give any file name ?

I do not know the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

The function `GetFileName` does not work for multiple selected files (see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ase8xye4.aspx) page explaining about the use of `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`).

Use the `GetStartPosition` / `GetNextPathName` functions as you are already doing in your code snippet.

If you just want to get the filename, and not the full path to each file, consider using the `splitpath` function as shown in this example: [splitpath quesion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520560/get-a-file-name-from-a-path)

Edit:
To wrap up getting the file name, you could add in a function similar to:

```
CString GetFileName(const CString& filePath)
{
    TCHAR   drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    TCHAR   dir[_MAX_DIR];
    TCHAR   fname[_MAX_FNAME];
    TCHAR   ext[_MAX_EXT];

    _tsplitpath_s(filePath, drive, dir, fname, ext);

    CString fileName;
    fileName.Format(_T("%s%s"), fname, ext);
    return fileName;
}
```

Then replace the code that displays the message box with:

```
AfxMessageBox(GetFileName(PathName));
```

That worked for me when I added it to your code example.

Comment: I did not get what you want to say....I have gone through the link but any other suggestion ?

Comment: I've added a suggestion of how to use splitpath for getting the filename.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
CFileDialog fOpenDlg(TRUE,"", " ", OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, 
"Capture file (*.cap)|*.cap|", this);

fOpenDlg.m_pOFN->lpstrTitle="Import file";

fOpenDlg.m_pOFN->lpstrInitialDir="Desktop";

if(fOpenDlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
{
    POSITION pos=fOpenDlg.GetStartPosition();
    while(pos)
    {
        CString PathName=fOpenDlg.GetNextPathName(pos);
        CString strFileName= ::PathFindFileName(PathName);
        AfxMessageBox(strFileName);
    }
}
```

Notice the `CString strFileName= ::PathFindFileName(PathName);` line.