# c++ copying directory into an another directory (linux cp command)

Tags: c++, linux, directory, cp

I'm trying to implement cp -r command so that when user types in cp -r dir dir1, dir gets copied and pasted inside dir1. Below is what i have so far and it does copy the files and directories inside the directory, but it doesn't copy directory itself. For example, when there is a file1 and a directory 'a'inside dir then it will only copy and paste file1 and 'a' inside of dir1, but not the directory dir itself. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You start your algorithm one step too deep into the directory you are copying: `dir_entry = readdir(dir)` reads all the entrys **inside** your source directory and therefore the source directory itself is not copied.

The function is fine, you just need one extra step before you call it.

Instead of calling `dirCopy("a", "b")` you need to start by executing

```
mkdir("b/a", convertMode("a"));
```

and then

```
dirCopy("a", "b/a");
```

So you are going to need code that extracts the last filename part from your `path` so you can then append it to `newPath`. If you need assistance for that you can look at this question: [Get a file name from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520560/get-a-file-name-from-a-path)